# asyncio wait on multiple tasks with timeout and cancellation

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have some code that runs multiple tasks in a loop like this:

```
    done, running = await asyncio.wait(running, timeout=timeout_seconds,
                                       return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

I need to be able to determine *which* of these timed out.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#timeouts):

> Note that this function does not raise asyncio.TimeoutError. Futures or Tasks that aren’t done when the timeout occurs are simply returned in the second set.

I could use `wait_for()` instead, but that function only accepts a single awaitable, whereas I need to specify multiple.  Is there any way to determine which one from the set of awaitables I passed to `wait()` was responsible for the timeout?

Alternatively, is there a way to use `wait_for()` with multiple awaitables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can try that tricks, probably it is not good solution:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    return 42

async def need_some_sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(1000)
    return 42


async def coro_wrapper(coro):
    result = await asyncio.wait_for(coro(), timeout=10)
    return result

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

done, running = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(
    [coro_wrapper(foo), coro_wrapper(need_some_sleep)],
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
    )
)

for item in done:
    print(item.result())

print(done, running)
```

Comment: I don't think this works.  `asyncio.wait()` doesn't appear to do *anything* to the underlying Task.  In particular, it doesn't set an exception on it.  In a real world case I'm dealing with, `len(done) == 0` and `len(running) == 7`.  One of those `running` things timed out, but I don't know which one.  And calling `r.exception()` on every one of them raises an `InvalidStateException` saying "Exception has not been set."

Comment: You will not get an exception, asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError will occur if all coroutines have exceeded timeout or at least one has been executed

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your suggestion.  The documentation says "If the Future isn’t done yet, this method raises an InvalidStateError exception."  Also, `wait()` says "Note that this function does not raise asyncio.TimeoutError. Futures or Tasks that aren’t done when the timeout occurs are simply returned in the second set."   The timeout expired, but the task isn't done, therefore `exception()` raises `InvalidStateError`.  I also tried your suggestion in code and it didn't solve the problem, because it doesn't allow me to determine which of the tasks timed out.  What am I missing?

Comment: Waiiiiit..  I think I get it.  Since the timeout is global to every awaitable in the set, either all tasks timed out, or none timed out.  Is this correct?

Comment: Your right,all awaitables will be interrupted. Or in your case they will be interrupted if any task will be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it:

```py
done, pending = await asyncio.wait({
    asyncio.create_task(task, name=index)
        for index, task in enumerate([
            my_coroutine(),
            my_coroutine(),
            my_coroutine(),
        ])
    },
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
)

num = next(t.get_name() for t in done)

if num == 2:
    pass
```

Use `enumerate` to name the tasks as they are created.